# Kubernetes nginx redirect to user-specified url

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

Sorry i'm new to all that, i have 2 springboot app deployed and exposed (using services) which i can reach using < Minikube IP >:< Port > and i want to use ingress to expose the apps.

I've this ingress config to expose 2 kubernetes services.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: esse-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 rules:
 - host: mssmdns.dz
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /esse-1/*
       backend:
         serviceName: esse-service-1
         servicePort: 8080
     - path: /esse-2/*
       backend:
         serviceName: esse-service-2
         servicePort: 8080
```

I want to redirect incoming request as follow:

http://mssmdns.dz/esse-1/a/b/c (from outside) **->** http://mssmdns.dz/a/b/c (inside the app)

(and same for esse-2).

When i write any url i'm being stuck in the same page (the / url)
I'm using kubernetes and nginx as ingress controller.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) documentation provides an [example rewrite configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/).

It uses regular expressions on the path and then uses the second matching group from the regex in the `rewrite-target` annotation.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: esse-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
 rules:
 - host: mssmdns.dz
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /esse-1(/|$)(.*)
       backend:
         serviceName: esse-service-1
         servicePort: 8080
     - path: /esse-2(/|$)(.*)
       backend:
         serviceName: esse-service-2
         servicePort: 8080
```